# How to generate a list of selections for a dropdown menu from a column in my database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a form "formA" with a hidden input.  The input is named "email".  This input is hidden and contains the value of a logged in users email.  This input is not meant to be filled in and is already populated with a logged in users email address upon page load.  With that said I have a database and a table named "table_A" with 3 columns.  "id" "email" & "itemname".  The column "itemname" has values that i need to be generated as selections in my dropdown menu named "drop_down".  I need the values under the column "email" from my database to be generated as selections under my drop down menu ONLY if the column value of "email" is equal to that of the value of the forms input "email".

Heres a pic that might help its a  mock up of what it should look like:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/20rtzpz.jpg

### CODE

```
<html>
<header>



</header>

<body>

<form action="/demoform/contact_form.php" id="formA" method="post" name="formA">

<big>LOAD PAST ORDERS:</big>

<select id="drop_down" name="drop_down">

<option value="">Please select...</option>

</select>



<input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>



<input id="email" name="email" type="text"   value="demo@gmail.com" readonly="readonly"/>


<input id="itemname" name="itemname" type="text" />



<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Much thanks and appreciation for any time and help with this thanks.

Comment: You already asked this question and I supplied you with the answer.

Comment: trust me i wouldn't be here if it had worked out for me...

Answer (score 0):

You query your database with something like

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE email=".$email
```

then get the result in form of an array.

When you are printing the HTML you do something like this

```
<select id="drop_down" name="drop_down">
   <?php foreach($array_results as $row) : ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['key'];?>" ><?php echo $row['itemname'];</option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks...looks like what I'm looking for...could you possibly explain how would i go about adapting this to my code...my coding skills are not as good

Comment: *Ah,* so that's where the OP got `$sql="SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE email=".$email` from (posted a new question with your code, but has since changed it because of what I told him). An Email **will** be a string, therefore it needs to be changed to `$sql="SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE email='".$email."'";` otherwise SQL **will** throw an error.

Comment: What kind of functions do you use to connect to your database, do you use any kind of framework?